# Concatenate prefix with value of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a translate directive that I can use like this:

```
{{'label.name' | translate}}
```

And `label.name` is declared somewhere in a .json file.

Now I'm inside an `ng-repeat`;

```
<ul ng-repeat="val in vals">
  {{val}}
</ul>
```

I can't use `{{val | translate}}` because val doesn't have the `label.`something prefix.

How do I concatenate in this case? I tried `{{'label'+[val] | translate}}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
<ul ng-repeat="val in vals">
  {{'label.'+val | translate}}
</ul>
```

This will prefix label in it. Or you can even use your code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="val in vals">
  {{'label.'+[val] | translate}}
</ul>
```

For simplicity I have created [a jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ank9803/2t5yvj6k/1/).

Comment: No, is doesn't equal to `{{'label.name' | translate}}
`

Comment: Can you please clarify it further

Answer (score 0):

You need the property so must include `.` to get the object property

```
<ul ng-repeat="val in vals">
   {{"label."+val | translate}}
</ul>
```